# Redirecting to other url during Authentication using Next auth

Tags: reactjs, oauth-2.0, vercel, next.js13, next-auth

I deployed my site on vercel [Link](https://react-intern-assignment-gamma.vercel.app/) and had configured everything from .env variables to everything. I had set the NEXTAUTH_URL to the site domain which is  `https://react-intern-assignment-gamma.vercel.app/` . But when i click on sign in with google on login page. It redirects to this url `https://react-intern-assignment-cjk7how6u-shaik-mohd-huzaifa.vercel.app/api/auth/error`. Which is the previous deployment URL. So what i did is i deleted the site and deployed again. No its redirecting to the same thing. Help me fix it.

- For authenication i have used Next Auth. And only used google auth provider.

Comment: double check your config in google's dev console

Comment: Like what are the main things i should check out @alivarastepour

Comment: make sure you have included the correct origin(s) in Authorized javascript origins; considering given info, `https://react-intern-assignment-gamma.vercel.app` should be added. Also make sure that Authorized redirect URIs are properly set. In your case it should be `https://react-intern-assignment-gamma.vercel.app/api/auth/callback/google` . You can double check your credentials too.

Comment: Not working. Can you check out by checking on it @alivarastepour